# How do I swap first and last names with a comma and add a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame where the index is the names. But the names are first name, last name*

the data looks like this

```
Index          Sales
Jones, Mike*   500
James, Amy     300
```

The goal is to have (or have index be changed to names)

```
Index         Sales    Special 
Mike Jones     500       1
Amy James      300       0
```

where if the there is an * a new column is created that has 1 if there is a * or 0 if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# swap the first name and last name by splitting on the comma then using the .str attribute and reversing the list
print(df.index.str.split(',').str[::-1])

Index([[' Mike*', 'Jones'], [' Amy', 'James']], dtype='object')

# convert to series and .join the values in each row, then set as the index
df.set_index(pd.Series(df.index.str.split(',').str[::-1]).apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x)), inplace=True)
print(df)

              Sales
 Mike* Jones    500
 Amy James      300

# create a new column called "Special" and check where the index contains a "*"
# note you have to use "\*" because * is a special character
df['Special'] = df.index.str.contains('\*').astype(int)
print(df)

              Sales  Special
 Mike* Jones    500        1
 Amy James      300        0

# reassign the index after you replace the * with a blank ''
df.index = df.index.str.replace('\*', '')
print(df)

             Sales  Special
 Mike Jones    500        1
 Amy James     300        0
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `Index` as index column:

```
In [32]: df['Special'] = df.index.str.endswith('*').astype(int)                                                 

In [33]: df.set_index(df.index.str.replace(r'^(\w+),\s+(\w+)\*?', '\\2 \\1', regex=True))                       
Out[33]: 
            Sales  Special
Index                     
Mike Jones    500        1
Amy James     300        0
```

---

Details:

- `df.index.str.endswith('*').astype(int)` - check if `index` column value ends with `*` and cast logical result to integer value (being `0` or `1`)
- `df.index.str.replace(r'^(\w+),\s+(\w+)\*?', '\\2 \\1', regex=True)`- replace `index` column value with the contents of 1st and 2nd regex captured groups `(\w+)` swapping their positions with `\\2 \\1` (2nd followed by 1st)

Comment: Can you explain how the `replace` is swapping the first and last names while also removing the `*`?

Comment: @IanThompson, yes. see my explanation

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution to this that I can see is to use `iterrows()`. You would first intialize the `special` column to be all zeros, `df['special']=0`. Then iterate through the rows correcting each index and making the special equal 1 where needed.

Something like this

```py
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    if '*' in i:
            df.loc[i]['Special'] = 1
    df.rename(index={i: (i.split(',')[1] +' '+ i.split(',')[0]).replace('*','')}, inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe and `'Index'` is the index. If `'Index'` is just a column, remove the `reset_index` and the `set_index` calls.

```
ddf = df.reset_index()
ddf['Special'] = ddf['Index'].str.contains('\*').astype(int)
ddf['Index'] = ddf['Index'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.split(',')[::-1]).replace('*', '').strip())
ddf.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
```

`ddf` is the result:

```
            Sales  Special
Index                     
Mike Jones    500        1
Amy James     300        0
```